# Prime Numbers and Canonical Factorization.

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Find $n$ such that $2^{n} \mid 3^{1024}−1$, where $n$ is an integer. I factorized $3^{1024}−1$ as $a^{2}-b^{2}$ and showed $2 \mid 3^{1024}-1$. Help me to get $n$.

Comment: You should try to solve such a problem yourself before posting.  Notice that the number of times $2$ is a factor of $3^{1024}-1$ is the sum of the number of times $2$ divides $3^{512}-1$ and times it divides $3^{512}+1$.  Moreover $4$ cannot divide both of those factors, because they differ by exactly $2$.  So with a bit of work you can report your progress in tackling this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^n||3^{1024}-1$$

We know that $2^{10}=1024$ and $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Now,
$$3^{2^{10}}=(3^{2^9}+1)(3^{2^9}1)$$
$$=(3^{2^9}+1)(3^{2^8}+1)(3^{2^8}-1)$$
$$=(3^{2^9}+1)(3^{2^8}+1)(3^{2^7}+1)(3^{2^7}-1)$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$=(3^{2^9}+1)(3^{2^8}+1)(3^{2^7}+1)....(3^{2^1}+1)(3^{2^0}+1)(3-1)$$
To find the largest $n$, $2^n||3^{1024}-1$, $2^n$ should divide $3^{1024}-1$
$$3^{2^{10}}=(3^{2^9}+1)(3^{2^8}+1)(3^{2^7}+1)(3^{2^6}+1)(3^{2^5}+1)(3^{2^4}+1)(3^{2^3}+1)(3^{2^2}+1)(3^{2^1}+1)(3^{2^0}+1)(3-1)$$

Note that each factor divides $2$ only once except $3^{2^0}+1$ which divides it by $2$ times

Therefore, there $11$ factors out of which $3^{2^0}+1$ divides $2$ times.
$$n=12$$

Comment: To clarify: $4 \nmid 3^{2^i} + 1$ for $i \geq 1$ because here $3^{2^i} + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$.